# Custom scale printing in Adobe Acrobat

Tags: printing, adobe-acrobat, scaling

I have Acrobat X Pro and [read](https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/using/printing-pdfs-custom-sizes.html)

1. Choose File > Print.
2. Click Size, and choose one of the following options:

   - **Fit** Scales small pages up and large pages down to fit the paper.
   - **Shrink** Oversize Pages
   - **Resizes** only large pages to fit the paper, and prints small pages as    they are.
   - **Custom scale** Resizes pages by the percentage you specify.
     Note: If you don’t see a Page Scaling options, click the arrow next to the Printer menu to expose more controls in the Print dialog box.

I do see all options except the latter. What is the arrow next to the Printer Menu? Why does Adobe pass the scaling buck to the printer, why custom scaling is hidden in my case?

Answer (score 0):

I checked it in Acrobat and Reader X on Mac, and the fixed scaling option is not present. It could be that what you read online is for Acrobat XI or DC.

There is a workaround for a fixed scaling. Switch to the Poster option, and there you can enter your fixed scaling value.

And that should do it.

Comment: I have this `Poster` mode but it makes tiles -- prints one page into multiple sheets of paper. If I disable the tiling, it does not scale anything. The effect of zooming center of the page at the cost of cropping the margins is not achieved.

Comment: Look at the preview; if the scaling is so that it fills simply one page, it will not create multiple sheets. If, OTOH, your scaled page is bigger than the paper size selected, you will (of course) end up with more than one sheet of paper to get all the contents out.